# How can I output a list in random order?

Tags: python

I was writing some code for a "map chooser" and want it to cycle through maps in a line

Here's the code:

```
maps = ["moon", "earth", "mars", "venus", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "houses", "floodland"]
while True:
    map = random.choice(maps)
    sys.stdout.write(map)
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Desired result is it cycling through all the maps in a single line, choosing a map, showing it, choosing another map, **removing the other map** and showing the new map in the same line and so on. What I actually get is the maps getting mixed up with each other like, I get earthland when it cycles through FloodLand and Earth.

What is the problem and how I can resolve it?

Comment: When I'm randomly choosing one item, it's supposed to cycle through them, like, "earth", "floodland", etc but what I get is earthland and other mixed up entries. And, when I mean mixed up, I mean the entries are containing text from other entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arise when using `sys.stdout.write("\r")`. You are basically telling the program to go at the beginning of the line and write the new map from there. When you wrote a longer map before you have some leftovers character at the end when writing a new one.

The fix really depends on the terminal you're printing on.
If you can afford an additional variable this solution should work almost everywhere:

```
maps = ["moon", "earth", "mars", "venus", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "houses", "floodland"]
last_print_len = 0
while True:
    current_map = random.choice(maps)
    empty = last_print_len - len(current_map) if last_print_len > len(current_map) else 0
    sys.stdout.write(current_map + " " * empty + "\r")
    last_print_len = len(maps)
    time.sleep(1)
```

If not, you can try something like:

```
maps = ["moon", "earth", "mars", "venus", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "houses", "floodland"]
while True:
    current_map = random.choice(maps)
    sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')    # Erase and go at the beginning of line  
    sys.stdout.write(current_map + "\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>If I understood your question correctly you actually need to use "\n" - line break and not "\r" carriage return. Carriage return - makes your code overwrite text every iteration.</s>

Try this:

```py
maps = ["moon", "earth", "mars", "venus", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "houses", "floodland"]
while True:
    current_map = random.choice(maps)
    sys.stdout.write(current_map)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT**

My modified version, another variant:

```py
import random
import time

maps = ["moon", "earth", "mars", "venus", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune", "houses", "floodland"]
random.shuffle(maps)

while (rand_map := maps.pop() if maps else None):
    print('\033[2K\033[1G{}'.format(rand_map), end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You are using the \n linebreak, it shows everything in a newline. This not what I want. I want it to choose a map, show it, and choose another map, remove the old map, show the new map and so on.

Comment: I see, sorry for the not relevant answer. Made another variant just for the record and for fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint

map_length= len(maps)

for _ in range(map_length):
    index = int(randint(0,map_length))
    print(maps[index])
```